# what is the equivalent of of .error for .then in angular $http

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, server

Im trying to show a different message if there is a server error or whatever using Angular:

```
  $http.post(url,data).then(function(data) {//code if successful});
```

but the response always seems to be 200 even when I deliberatly put a error like a parse error in the server side script. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: If you are getting a 200 response, then your issue is with the server code not Angular.

Comment: `$http` returns a promise. And like all of angulars promises errors are handled either in an optional second callback to a `.then()` or even better in a `.catch()`. It is also worth noting `$http` had helper `.success()` and `.error()` they have now been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for handling a success/error response to your $http req would look something like this.

```
$http.post(url, data)
     .then( function(success){
                // do success things
            },
            function(error){
                // do error things
            });
```

I recommend reading the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

However, if you're still getting a 200, it is likely a server issue.

Comment: if i actually go to the site it says error 500 but i get a 200 response back from angular